# How to make a real time 2D Density Plot with javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, real-time, density-plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS04u.png)

Url link for the graph: https://plot.ly/javascript/2d-density-plots/?fbclid=IwAR2JFdIcX2dMKnwmquwJy30NE2q6RTyaSgiSKiQLRl2q2Fo8VCCK0nTBbuc

Im currently developing a website that gets co-ordinate data from a database and then plots to a 2D density plot, but im having problems trying to make it work  in real time. I've seen examples with a line plot but this is massively different, I was wondering did anyone have any suggestions as to how I should approach this.

My thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data stream from your server or a websocket, when your data change you can listen the event in the frontend and re-draw or update your chart it depends of plotly options (e.g. https://community.plot.ly/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639/7). If you have Node.js backend the next links would be interesting for you:

- Streams: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html
- Websockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API